# Connecting to a MySQL Docker Container from Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I've provided my docker-compose and database config files below. I'm trying to connect my rails app to a containerized mysql instance.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: appname-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: approot
      MYSQL_DATABASE: appdb
      MYSQL_USER: app_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: app!
    ports:
      - "3309:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

```
# database.yml
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: 127.0.0.1 # i have tried 'db' and 'appname-mysql'
  username: root
  password: papercliproot
```

When I set `host: 127.0.0.1` I get this error `ActiveRecord::DatabaseConnectionError: There is an issue connecting to your database with your username/password, username: paperclip_user. (ActiveRecord::DatabaseConnectionError)`

Any help?

I have tried setting host to `127.0.0.1` and using the container name `db` defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file. I also tried `appname-mysql` which is the name of the container itself.

Comment: It seems there's a typo in your docker-compose file: `- "3309:3306"`
Unsure if it's intended, but if it is intended you should specify the port for your database.yml

Comment: @LeeKaiXuan ahh not a typo but that was the issue! my local mysql was blocking up that port so i used 3309 for the container. i also didn't realize there was a port option for the `database.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the port option to the database.yml file resolved the issue.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: paperclip_user
  password: paperclip!
  database: paperclipdb
  port: 3309
```